# JS / Скорость и направление прохождение курсора над объектом?

Tags: javascript, svg, hover

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно "считывать" скорость с которой пользователь провел курсором, над объектом ? Приведу простой пример

```js
var block = document.querySelector("#block"),
  value = document.querySelector("#value");

block.onmousemove = function(event) {
  value.innerHTML = event.target;
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#block {
  width: 184px;
  height: 184px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 184 186"><path d="M92 0l92 93-92 93L0 93 92 0z" fill="#13ff74"/><path d="M92 93h92l-92 93L0 93h92z" fill="#00bb75"/><path d="M92 0v186L0 93 92 0z" fill="#00c178"/><path d="M48.8 93H92v93L0 93h48.8z" fill="#009169"/><path d="M92 34.4L150.7 93 92 151.6 33.3 93 92 34.4z"/></svg>
</div>
<p id="value"></p>
```

Как узнать с какой скоростью, и в каком направлении (справа налево, или слева направо) над #block провели курсором мыши ?

Comment: А что Вы будете с этими данными  делать?

Comment: Во-первых узнать возможно ли это в принципе, просто документация пишет https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave Что якобы событие браузером может быть и не словлено, если очень быстро провели. Если всё же каким-то образом можно узнать, есть идея заставить данный объект вращаться по оси Y, и делать  с такой интенсивностью с какой пользователь провел над объектом. (Анимация вращения по Y)

Comment: Все верно, но желаемый эффект вполне достижим

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что от скорости движения курсора должно зависеть кол-во оборотов, которое сделает объект?

Comment: Да, всё верно, а направление движения курсора, в какую именно сторону оно вращается.

Comment: в объекте события есть текущие координаты курсора мыши, нужно сравнить на сколько они изменились с прошлого раза и в зависимости от этого считать скорость

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Так?

```js
var block = document.querySelector("#block");
var speed = 0;
var value = 0
var lastX = 0
document.body.onmousemove = function(event) {
  speed = lastX - event.x;
  lastX = event.x
};

requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw(){
  value += speed;
  speed *= 0.9;
  block.style.transform = `rotatey(${value}deg)`;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#block {
  width: 184px;
  height: 184px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 184 186">

  <path d="M92 0l92 93-92 93L0 93 92 0z" fill="#13ff74"/><path d="M92 93h92l-92 93L0 93h92z" fill="#00bb75"/><path d="M92 0v186L0 93 92 0z" fill="#00c178"/><path d="M48.8 93H92v93L0 93h48.8z" fill="#009169"/><path d="M92 34.4L150.7 93 92 151.6 33.3 93 92 34.4z"/>

  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: а как же обнулить переменные)

Comment: @NikitaUmnov я полагаю присвоением нуля, в необходимый момент :)

Comment: Спасибо, интересно получилось. А можно ли как-то реализовать, что б вращения задавались не по области элемента body а именно по пространству #block ? *Дело в том что таких элементов на странице предполагается размещать несколько, и хотелось бы что б они вращались независимо друг от друга

Comment: @BlackStar1991 нужно вешать на область, положение и размер которой не меняется, оберните еще блоком и повесьте на него